# Pythons socket,recvfrom() not working on Rasperry Pi

Tags: python, sockets

I want to communicate with a Art-Net node (its a network gadget to convert UDP Art-Net packets into DMX output, that is used in stage and film lighing) with a raspberry pi, running python on raspbian.

There are 2 problems with that code below, one has to do with the pi:
When running the code on my windows computer, everything works fine.
When running the same code (except a change in the ip address for the socket.bind), the code sends the ArtPoll packets, the node in the network replies with the ArtPollReply, but these packets aren't received by the python script. The code hangs at the line "data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(4096)" but nothing is giong to be received (there are packets to receive, the computer receives these packets at the same time).

Network config is okay, i checked everything. I checked also another artnet python thing, that worked - so there is no problem with the network interface itself.

Here is the whole demo code, that should demonstrate the problem.

```
import socket
import struct
import threading
import time

class PollThread(threading.Thread):      
def __init__(self, artnet):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.artnet = artnet

def run(self):
    while self.artnet.running:
        #break
        time.sleep(3)
        print self.artnet.nodes_ip
        self.artnet.ArtPoll()
    print "EXIT POLL THREAD"

class ArtNet(threading.Thread):
    nodes_ip = []
    nodes_data = []
    running = True
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.pollthread = PollThread(self)
        ip = "10.0.0.2"
        self.header_artpoll = self.set_Header_ArtPoll()
        #open socket
        try:      
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)                    
        except socket.error, msg:
            print 'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1]
        print '[INFO] Socket Created %s' % ip
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)         #Enable Broadcast
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)         #Diable Port blocking when reuse this port
        self.sock.bind((ip, 6454))

    def run(self):
        self.pollthread.start()
        while self.running:
            print "RECEIVING...."
            data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(4096)
            print "RECEIVED DATA!"
            print addr
            opcode = struct.unpack('<H', data[8:10])[0]
            if opcode == 0x2000:
                self.HandleArtPollReply(addr[0], data)
                #self.artnet_handler.ArtPollReply() 
            if opcode == 0x2100:
                self.HandleArtPollReply(addr[0], data)
        print "EXIT ARTNET THREAD"

    def set_Header_ArtPoll(self):
        header = []
       header.append("Art-Net\x00")                                        #ID
        header.append(struct.pack('<H', 0x2000))                            #OpCode
        header.append(struct.pack('>H', 14))                                #ProtVer
        header.append(struct.pack('>H', 0b00000000))                        #TalkToMe
        header.append(chr(0xe0))                                            #Priority
        header = "".join(header)
        return header

    def HandleArtPollReply(self, ip, data):
        self.nodes_ip.append(ip)
        self.nodes_data.append(data)

    def ArtPoll(self):         
        self.nodes_ip = []
        self.nodes_data = []
        self.sock.sendto(self.header_artpoll, ('<broadcast>', 6454))
        self.sock.sendto(self.header_artpoll, ('10.255.255.255', 6454))
        self.sock.sendto(self.header_artpoll, ('2.255.255.255', 6454))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    artnet = ArtNet()
    artnet.start()
    s = raw_input()
    artnet.sock.close()
    artnet.running = False
    print "MIAN EXIT"
```

EDIT:
Now I have additional information: if i bind to '', everything works fine, also on the pi.

```
self.sock.bind(('', 6454))
```

In the comments, I got the advice to use

```
self.sock.bind((socket.INADDR_ANY, 6454))
```

That throws an error:

```
self.sock.bind((socket.INADDR_ANY, 6454))
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

That works for me in the first run, but it can be, i have to use multiple interfaces on the system for different tasks - so i may use the ip based bind to the interface to difference their service provided.
EDIT END

The second problem is, i don't know how to close the ArtNet() Class, because when i do, the thread hangs at "data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(4096)" waiting for data. So I have to break this command. My idea is to send some data to the machine to unblock that thing....

EDIT:
I already use this self.sock.close() and the thread keeps running after close()

Comment: As for the final problem.... add a `close` method to the class that closes the socket and have whatever decides to terminate call that. The close should generate an error to `recvfrom`.

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason, you should bind to INADDR_ANY instead of a specific IP address.   This will stop you from having to change things when you move it between computers.   The only time you would want to specify the IP address is when you want to do some sort of routing across different networks.